# how to add a dynamic button using navparams in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an app in Ionic 2, I am using navparams tu grab the button pressed when pushing another page.
In this page I have a link that I want to generate dynamically using the params passed depending the buton pressed in the previous page.

So, I have homepage with button1, button2, button3.
I
In homepage I have this code:

```
  goToPage(){
  this.navCtrl.push(Page,{
    firstPassed: "param1"
  });
}
```

Then in the next Page I have:

```
export class Page {
  public firstParam:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, params: NavParams) {
  this.firstParam = params.get("parampassed");
}
```

If I add in the page.html:

```
<ion-title>{{firstParam}}</ion-title>
```

I get the params well, but what I want is to use that param as a link in a button, something like this in the page.ts:

```
    goToPage2(){
    this.navCtrl.push(page'parampassed');
  }
```

So it could take me to the page pageparam1.html

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: i am not understanding your question

Comment: Me neither...please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Well more simple, what I want to do is to use this result {{firstParam}} as a page to push or add it as a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create seperate pages (including .ts files) for Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3

Next import these in your 'NextPage'

make a button `<button (click)="goToPageWithParam()">Go to param page</button>`

Now in your NextPage create this function:

```
goToPageWithParam(){
    let page:any;
    if(this.firstParam == "button1"){
        page = Page1;
    }
    if(this.firstParam == "button2"){
        page = Page2;
    }

    //etc..
    //then at the end
    this.navCtrl.push(page);
}
```

I think this is a solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is what I want to do. The only problem is that I get an error, TypeError: this.firstParam is not a function. This is my code: export class Page2 {
      public firstParam:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, params: NavParams) {
      this.firstParam = params.get("firstPassed");
  }

  goToPageWithParam(){
    let page:any;
    if(this.firstParam() == "button1"){
        page = Page3;
    }
    if(this.firstParam() == "buton2"){
        page = Page4;
    }

    //etc..
    //then at the end
    this.navCtrl.push(page);
}

Comment: Fixed it! I removed the () after firstParam and now it is working, thank you!